# Missing Developer ID Application signing identity for (null)

Tags: xcode, upload, certificate

While trying to export a Developer ID Signed Mac application with Xcode I run into this error: "Missing Developer ID Application signing identity for (null)"  How do I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this issue for a while so wanted to post what I found in case others run into a similar issue. I ran into the above issue after revoking my certificate while trying to export my build from a friend's machine. I found the best support by going step by step through this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html

I would recommend following the steps in this link for anyone uploading a build to the Mac app store or exporting a Developer ID Signed Mac application.

There is a certificate called "Developer ID Certification Authority", this seems to be the one I was missing, and which caused the most trouble.

Another interesting thing to note is that the 10 digit letter/number ID for your Team/Distribution profile will be different than the ID for your developer profile. This should not throw you off, these two profiles work together.

Another good thing to know is that at the top of developer.apple.com there is a non-obvious drop down menu that lets you switch between iOS, tvOS, watchOS profiles and MacOS X profiles.
[image]

Another non-obvious UX issue when dealing with certificates is the system tab within Keychain Access. If you read that you should delete or change a property both within Login and within system, when they write system, they are referring to the system tab, which can be accessed within Key Chain access and can be seen at the bottom of this image:

[image]
This link is also helpful for certificate trouble shooting: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW11

But mainly just go through the steps in the first link given for exporting a Mac App with Developer ID Signing.